# svg pie chart with pure JS (no framework)

Tags: javascript, svg, pie-chart

I'm trying to code an svg pie chart using pure javascript and svg circle elements. I'm using the `stroke-dasharray` attribute to display the pie slices proportionally to the values stored in my array :

```
var percentList = [50, 35, 15];
```

This first step is working fine, but then I'm stuck trying to calculate the rotation angle of each slice according to their percent value to prevent mutual overlaying. Here is a picture reproducing the problem :

[image]

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lau1989/r3v3Lkqb/3/

One can see the green slice of the right pie is partially overlaying the blue one so it appears smaller than 50%, even though it really represents 50% of the pie. (comment/uncomment the green and yellow slices to check).

I know the problem comes from the `for` loop i'm using to calculate the rotation angle of each slice, but everything I tried so far didn't work and I came to the point where I can't think of any other solution.

```
for (var c = 0; c < circle_pies.length; c++) {
  sum += percentList[c]; 
  var angle = sum /100 * 360;
  svg_pies[c].style.transform = 'rotate('+(-90+angle)+'deg)';
}
```

My latest try was to add a decrementing for loop to keep track of all previous percent values for each slice, but it just made my problem harder to solve :
https://jsfiddle.net/Lau1989/wkbLbnac/

How should I adapt my code to get the right rotation angles ?

Please tell me if you think a different approach (e.g. using paths) would give a better cross-browser/good performance solution, but whatever solution I end up using I'm really dying to know what is wrong with my current code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might make the difference for you.

```
var angle = 180;
for (var c = 0; c < circle_pies.length; c++) {
  svg_pies[c].style.transform = 'rotate('+(-90+angle)+'deg)'; 
  angle = (angle + percentList[c] / 100 * 360) % 360;
}
```

You can change the initial angle to change the rotation of the whole chart. (You could also use a value of 90 to remove the `-90 +` in your rotation statement.

You can see this in action in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/rnLnqq3g/)**.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exaclty what I was trying to do. I actually didn't think of incrementing the angle at the end of the loop using the modulus operator. Very clean and elegant solution.

Comment: The modulus bit was simply a refinement.  I believe it would work without it.  The main thing was getting the right values at the right time.  And that was doing the increment at the end.